# MS Access aggregate function Query works on a single table but but not on multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions

This query works fine:

```
SELECT
    SessionResults.Driver,
    SUM( IIF( SessionResults.Place = 1, 1, NULL ) ) AS [Race Wins], 
    ROUND( AVG( SessionResults.Place ), 2 )         AS [Avg Race Pos], 
    SUM( SessionResults.TotalLaps )                 AS [Total Laps]
FROM
    SessionResults
GROUP BY
    SessionResults.Driver;
```

This one does not:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SessionResults.Driver,
    ( SUM( IIF( [SessionResults.Place] = 1, 1, NULL ) ) ) AS [Race Wins],
    ROUND( AVG( SessionResults.Place ), 2 )               AS [Avg Race Placing], 
    ROUND( AVG( SegmentData.SegPlace ), 2 )               AS [Avg Heat Placing], 
    COUNT( SessionResults.TotalLaps )                     AS [Total Laps], 
    EventHistory.TrackID                                  AS [Track/Layout],
    MAX( EventHistory.Date )                              AS [Last Race]
FROM
    SessionResults,
    SegmentData,
    EventHistory
WHERE
    (
        (
            ( SessionResults.EventID ) = EventHistory.EventID
            AND
            SegmentData.EventID = SessionResults.EventID
        )
    )
GROUP BY
    SessionResults.Driver,
    EventHistory.TrackID;
```

The second query produces excessive counts in the `[Race Wins]` column. The other columns appear to be accurate.

I know there are better ways to do this in newer Access versions but I'm not up to speed on those methods either.

What am I missing here? I messed with different Join options but couldn't get anything to work. Can this be done with Access? The version I'm running is very old, Access 2000, V9.

Again, a single table query seems to work fine. The data gets messed up in the `[Race Wins]` column when I extend the query to other tables within the same mdb file. The single table query produces a max of 36 wins in the `Race Wins` column. When the query is extended to multiple tables those numbers increase to well over 600 wins, which is not accurate.

Comment: That should be expected if these tables have 1-to-many or many-to-many relationships. Should use JOIN clauses instead of WHERE to link tables. Edit question to provide sample data as text tables.

Comment: Probably have to aggregate one or all of the tables separately then join.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not having much luck with joins either. These tables do have a lot of one-to-many and many-to-many relationships. I'll try to provide more detail. Thanks again for helping!

Comment: Your first table did not post properly. Shouldn't there be 3 tables? I meant provide sample raw data, not the query results. Probably more sample data than needed.

Comment: No, the first is a query on one table, and the second three tables.

Comment: Again, I suggest you provide raw data tables, not query results.

Comment: Sorry about the post, not sure what happened there. When you say "raw" data, do you mean the actual table schemas?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.